# Basic example of rendering a d3 SVG with a backbone View

Tags: backbone.js, svg, d3.js

I am trying to switch from static html SVGs (with dynamic values) to dynamic d3 SVGs in a Backbone view.   I am currently using templates (and would prefer to keep it that way for some of the other properties), but don't have to (as I can refactor those properties into their own view with template).

Anyone have a clean quick example, like with just a circle ?

The closest version of Backbone and d3 I found is [here](http://bl.ocks.org/zmaril/3094256), but this is what I want to get to, and don't have enough d3 experience yet to understand the function calls and structure yet.

The code that is currently providing the problem is in the render() of the View :

```
    var pathFunction = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function (d) {return d.x;})
        .y(function (d) {return d.y;})
        .interpolate("basis"); // bundle | basis | linear | cardinal are also options

    //The Circle SVG Path we draw
    var svgContainer = d3.select('#measure'+measure.cid);

    var circle = svgContainer.append("g")
        .append("path")
        .data([circleStates[0]])
        .attr("d", pathFunction)
        .attr("class", "circle");

    var compiledTemplate = _.template(this.representations[this.currentRepresentation], measureTemplateParamaters);
    $(this.el).find('.addMeasure').before( compiledTemplate );
```

basically I am trying to draw a circle with a path, defined by already computed points.   I just don't know how to get it passed to either the template or the DOM via the Backbone.View

Console Error when "Bead" is selected on [this](http://compthink.cs.vt.edu:3000) page:

```
Error: Problem parsing d="function line(data) {
  var segments = [], points = [], i = -1, n = data.length, d, fx = d3_functor(x), fy = d3_functor(y);
  function segment() {
    segments.push("                         jquery.js:6326
jQuery.extend.clean jquery.js:6326
jQuery.buildFragment jquery.js:6165
jQuery.fn.extend.domManip jquery.js:5975
jQuery.fn.extend.before jquery.js:5795
(anonymous function) measuresView.js:227
_.each._.forEach underscore.js:78
Backbone.View.extend.render measuresView.js:133
Backbone.View.extend.changeMeasureRepresentation measuresView.js:90
triggerEvents backbone.js:96
Backbone.Events.trigger backbone.js:187
Backbone.View.extend.cycle wholeMeasureRepresentationView.js:46
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:3059
elemData.handle.eventHandle jquery.js:2677
```

This is the full error , and doesn't match my code, leading me to believe this seems like it is trying to take d3's function and render that, not what I expect d3 to return.  The stack trace eventually leads me back to the compiledTemplate that gets passed in (`(anonymous function) measuresView.js:227`), and that is what I am trying to figure out, How to pass the d3 SVG into the template.

Comment: That example you posted is pretty complete.  What part are you missing?  How to render a template and then inject content using d3.js?

Comment: You'll have to post some more code, and optionally include a jsFiddle in addition to the code that reproduces your issue.

Comment: I have minimized the file as much as possible in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisfrisina/6a6da/), however, I don't know how to elminate require.js, and I don't think the template is correctly passed as a string like the `!text` version is. I did however psuh the changes to the site [here](http://compthink.cs.vt.edu:3000) so you can see the error. Just switch the "measure representation" to Bead, and you can see the error in the console. For full code, you can see it [here](http://bit.ly/11SElsU). THX for your help! Trying to replace with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisfrisina/6sYAY/)

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors in the site that you pushed to.  Can you post the error you are seeing in the console, the line number ect.

Comment: The error only comes up once you select the "bead" representation under "measure representations".   but I placed the error up top in the original question...

Comment: Any clue on how to pass the d3 SVG into the template?, or what Im missing?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by pass the svg to the template.  What you really want to do is in the view's render function render the template, append the html to the dom, then use an element from the template as the root element for your visualization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue your having is in the bead template.  In the template you reference the property `pathFunction`, which is a function, where you should be referencing the return value of that function.  Just change `pathFunction` to `pathFunction()` and you should be fine assuming that the pathFunction is written to return an svg path without any arguments.  If that is the case, here is the way the template should look:

```
<div id="measure<%= measure.cid %>" class="measure">
  <div class="btn" id="a">Unroll</div>
  <div class="btn" id="b">Rollup</div>
  <span class="title">Measure <span class="number"><%= measureCount %></span>
  <% if(measureCount == 1) { %>
  <% } else { %>
   - <span class="delete">[X]</span>
  <% } %>
  </span>
  <svg id="svg<%= measure.cid %>" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" class="circular-pie">
    <path d="<%= pathFunction() %>" />
    <!-- <circle cx="<%= cx %>" cy="<%= cy %>" r="<%= measureR %>" stroke="black" stroke-dasharray="1,3" stroke-width="1" fill="none" /> -->
    <g id="<%= beatHolder %>">
    </g>
  </svg> 
</div>
```

As far as what you are trying to achieve though, I think you what you want to do is to render an SVG element as part of your template, then after appending the HTML to the DOM, use the SVG element as the root of your visualization, so:

```
    // This should be in your view's render function
    // Render the template
    var compiledTemplate = _.template(this.representations[this.currentRepresentation], measureTemplateParamaters);
    // Insert the html into the DOM
    d3.select('#someContainer').html(compiledTemplate);
    // Then draw your visualization
    var pathFunction = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function (d) {return d.x;})
        .y(function (d) {return d.y;})
        .interpolate("basis");

    //The Circle SVG Path we draw
    var svgContainer = d3.select('#measure'+measure.cid);

    var circle = svgContainer.append("g")
        .append("path")
        .data([circleStates[0]])
        .attr("d", pathFunction(/*you'll need to insert some coordinate 
            information here see http://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-paths-and-d3js*/))
        .attr("class", "circle");
    // Do some other stuff
```

Comment: thanks for the help.   I got it.   I didnt know that I had to create the template first, then apply/attach d3 to the template.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're using the same string delimiter `"` for your xml and inside your function. JQuery tries to parse your compiled template and fails to evaluate the function in the 'd' attribute that stops at `...segments.push(`.

Change `segments.push("M"` into `segments.push('M'` and `segments.join("")` into `segments.join('')`and you should be fine.

Comment: That is JQuery code.  That is not my code.   I updated all double quotes in my code to be single quotes, and nothing changed, same error.   I have updated the github link to show the new code.  I think  it is in the compiling of the template, and that I am not passing the parameters correctly, or compiling the template correctly.